# NextJS Apollo "queryData.ssrInitiated is not a function" error on routing

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo, react-apollo, react-apollo-hooks

I have a page `items/[id]` for creating and editing items. I use -1 as item id for new items to differentiate create and edit mode. It is a functional component and looks like below

```
const getItem = (id) => {
    if (id > 0) {
        return useQuery(GET_ITEM_DETAILS, { variables: { id }})
    }
    return { loading: false, data: { product: {} } }
}

const itemForm = (props) => {
    const { loading, error, data } = getItem(props.id)

    /* RENDERING LOGIC*/
}
```

Form submit invokes either a create or update mutation based on id value. In the `onCompleted` handler of the create mutation I have added a router call to update the id as below:

```
router.replace(`/items/[id]`, `/items/${id}`)
```

When this routing happens I get an error on the `useQuery`.

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: queryData.ssrInitiated is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

The Runtime Error is occurring because of how React handles hooks and rendering. Using NextJS's `router.replace()` attempts to transition into the same page without reloading it, possibly causing issues with the `useQuery` hook.

Simply using `window.location` should solve the issue:

```
window.location.replace(`/items/${id}`)
```